# span element for uploading image overlapping above button

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I created a form for writing articles. 
The form consists of a text_field for title, a text_area for content, a button for submitting the form, and a file_field for uploading images.
Belows is the code:

```
<%= form_for(@atp_article, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="article_field">
        <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Write the article's title..." %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new article..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <span class="picture"> <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %> </span>
<% end %>
```

The `file_field` is supposed to have a 10px margin from the above element, as you can see from the style I chose:

```
span.picture {
  margin-top: 10px;
  input {
    border: 0;
  }
}
```

However the `span` element with class `.picture` overlaps the above button, also ignoring style, as you can see from the [image](http://imgbox.com/nAaIRD1f) I uploaded at imgbox.

The entire code containing the form is:

```
<div class="atp_articles_form">
    <strong> Write below any useful ATP piece of news </strong>
    <section class="atp_article_form">
        <%= render 'shared/atp_article_form' %>
    </section>
</div>
```

The `.atp_articles_form` class has 30px top and bottom padding. There is no other style. 
Another section of my application is using the style above, and it works: the span element with class `.picture` results 29px high as the included `input` element, as stays on its place at 10px below from the button. Instead, in this case, the span element with class `.picture` results 75px high, while the included `input` element is 29px. I do not understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `span` is [an inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span). I get the feeling from your description that you would like it to behave like a block-level element (honoring e.g. the 10px margin you gave it. In that case you should add `display: block;` to your CSS code, e.g:

```
span.picture {
  display: block; // this makes it a block-level element
  margin-top: 10px;
  input {
    border: 0;
  }
}
```